# Firebase Security Rules: How to implement firestore security rule when creating a document using set()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a chat app where I have a rooms collection in which the users can create rooms with the name of the room used as the room id. This is the code that creates the room:

```
const roomRef = firestore.collection('rooms').doc(formvalue);
const doc = await roomRef.get();
if(doc.exists){
  alert("Room already exists");
  setFormvalue("");
  setLoading(false);
}else {
  await roomRef.set({
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    lastMsg: `${user.displayName} created room ${formvalue}`,
    lastSeen: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    owner: user.email,
    participants: [user.email]
  })
}
```

But when I used this security rule:

```
match /rooms/{roomId}{
 allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email in resource.data.participants;
 allow create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

firestore denied the request. So then I tried this which also got denied:

```
match /rooms/{roomId}{
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && resource != null && request.auth.token.email in resource.data.participants;
  allow update: if request.auth != null && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/rooms/$(request.resource.id));
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

Then I tried this which to my surprise also got denied:

```
match /rooms/{roomId}{
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && resource != null && request.auth.token.email in resource.data.participants;
  allow write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. All other requests are blocked by this:

```
match /{document=**} {
   allow read, write: if false
}
```

P.PS. Other actions like reading and updating existing documents are working as expected.